# Cell Contains String with Relative Cell Reference Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet where I want to see if a column contains a certain String. If this is the case TRUE shall be returned, FALSE otherwise.

Here is what I tried, resulting in #VALUE!:

```
IF(SEARCH(A2, 'Dashboard Table'!A16:A), TRUE, FALSE)
```

What to do? 
Thanks
Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula returns `#VALUE!` because `IF` requires a boolean value (0 is considered as `FALSE`, 1 or greater numbers are considered as `TRUE`) as the first argument, but `SEARCH` returns `#N/A!` if the text to search is not found, by the other hand `SEARCH` looks for the text on a cell value.

The following formula will return a array of `TRUE`/`FALSE` values, TRUE when the value of `A2` is found, `FALSE` when not on cells `A16:A`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(A2, 'Dashboard Table'!A16:A),FALSE), TRUE, FALSE))
```

To get a single TRUE when the text to searh is found on any cell on A16:A use

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(sum(IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(A2, 'Dashboard Table'!A16:A),0), 1, 0))>0)
```

Comment: Is this possible without the ARRAYFORMULA? Because I do not want an Array of TRUES and FALSES. I just want one TRUE, when the content of "A2" is found in "Dashboard Table!A16:A". Otherwise only one FALSE. I could not get it to work.